# how to set css property from serverside asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i set the css (background)property from the server? Does not work at the moment:(

cs

```
 public string MyBackgroundColor { get; set; }
```

aspx

```
<style type="text/css">
    html
    {
        background-color: '<%=MyBackgroundColor %>';
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't show up at all or that it isn't showing the color you expect? Do you see the value in the rendered HTML? I would remove the single quotes for one.

And, are you assigning a value to MyBackgroundColor somewhere? You don't share enough code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

.aspx

```
<body id="body" runat="server">
...the body
```

.aspx.cs

```
body.Style["Background-Color"] = blue;//just example you can try using your method too
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(
    new LiteralControl(
        @"<style type='text/css'>
                html
                {
                    background-color: red;

                }
                </style>
            "
        )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your style tag is in the `<head>` element, change the `=` to a `#` (`background-color: '<%#MyBackgroundColor %>';`) add a `runat="server"` to the `<head>` element and call `Page.Header.DataBind()` in the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

`yourPageOrControlInstance.Styles["background"] = "yellow blah-blah";`